# Passing a reference of an object to an instance variable of a class, No viable overloaded '='

Tags: c++

I'm more of a Java programmer, but I currently have to use C++ to do a project.

I'm stuck on trying to pass a reference of an object to an instance variable of another object, (a IS-A relation). Basically, assigning a reference of ofApp to the MyMesh class &context variable.

However, doing so returns a no viable overloaded '=' error.

Here is mesh.hpp, mesh.cpp:

```
#ifndef mesh_hpp
#define mesh_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class ofApp;

class Triangle {
public:
    Triangle(int i1, int i2, int i3) { vertInd[0] = i1, vertInd[1] = i2, vertInd[2] = i3; }
    int vertInd[3];
};

class MyMesh {
public:
    MyMesh(ofApp& context);
    
    
    vector<glm::vec3> verts;
    vector<Triangle> triangles;
     
//    vector<std::array<int, 3>> triangleIndices;
    
    ofApp &context;
    
    
};

#endif /* mesh_hpp */

#include "mesh.hpp"

class ofApp;

MyMesh::MyMesh(ofApp& acontext){
    context = acontext; //no viable overloaded '='
}
```

Here is ofApp.h, ofApp.cpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "mesh.hpp"

class MyMesh;

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

    public:
        ofApp();

        MyMesh &mesh;
        
};

ofApp::ofApp(){
    mesh = MyMesh(*this);
}
```

Comment: The "references" of C++ have only the name in common with the "references" of Java. Why are you using them here? (The languages have very little in common beyond punctuation and the spelling of some keywords.)

Comment: You will have a hard time make this work (read: impossible) when your classes have mutual references to each other. I suggest you redo the design.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm trying to pass the ofApp object to the Mesh class, so that the ofApp object is accessible when using the Mesh class. In Java you can simply just pass the object "address" and the mesh variable will be assigned, perhaps I'm doing it wrong in this case?

Comment: @j6t I actually encountered the problem when importing the two files where it has mutual references to each other. I remember reading that the solution is to create a forward reference to the class, and have all instance variables in a class be declared as a pointer/reference. Perhaps I understood it wrongly?

Comment: @zychin You problem will be: to instantiate a `ofApp`, you'll need an instance of `MyMesh`, but to instantiate a `MyMesh`, you'll need a `ofApp` first. The reference members require this. There's no way to make this work without cheating. It points out a weakness in the design. (Since you come from Java, I suspect this is a desire to bring in object orientation in an over-eager manner.)

Comment: @j6t I can see that `ofApp` requires`MyMesh`, but why would `MyMesh` require `ofApp`? I presume it is not possible to pass an object which has not been fully constructed in C++?

Comment: @zychin `MyMesh` has a reference member to `ofApp`, so it requires a fully constructed `ofApp` to initialize `MyMesh`.

Answer (score 3):

in c++, the reference variable must be initialised at declaration and you cannot change the reference binding, the initialization canot be delayed. So if you want to set the reference in later time, you should use pointer.

Comment: I see. Basically, a reference is basically a pointer that is final and cannot be changed?

Comment: @zychin you can think of a reference as an alias for the actual object. It must be initialized and cannot be rebound.

Comment: yes, the reference in c++ is implemented the same as a pointer by compiler, but progammers will have no sense of that. and after initialization, you canot change it to refers another object, and reference will never be null, so it is not  flexible as pointers, but makes codes more simple and readable.